# Anime in which the protagonist is a kid that finds a robot and they fight robot battles

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am trying to recall an anime, in which the main character is a kid and somehow he finds a robot and they fight robot battles just like in *Big Hero 6*, but here the robots are huge and people operate it from the inside. Similar to the robot fighting championships from *Real Steel* where people earn fame and money by being the pilots for the robots.

Comment: Can you remember any more details? Such as when you watched it or what language it was in? Whether it was new or old, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Ooh I was looking for that anime one but couldn't remember when it was asked.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a lot of shows from the brief description you gave but the first one that jumped into my mind was [*Megas_XLR*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megas_XLR).

- This has a kid finding a giant robot from the future that you sit inside to pilot.
- He fights many other giant mechas, mostly from aliens called Glorft who had invaded earth in the future.

There is even an episode where they have a robot fighting championship.

Comment: Chicks dig giant robots

Answer (score 2):

It's very possibly [Red Baron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Baron_(anime)).

[image]

> In the future, the "Metal Fight" games are the most popular televised
>   sport in the world and many robot contestants compete for the title of
>   Best Metal Fighter in the World.
>
> Kurenai Ken, along with teammate Saeba Shôko (who was, at first,
>   adamantly opposed), pilots the Super Robot Fighter, Red Baron and
>   enters the contest with dreams of becoming its champion. He must,
>   however, face an army of other rivals from around the world including
>   "Kaizer" and the Tetsumen Tô doctors, and later allies like Tiger and
>   ShinRon.

[Opening theme](https://youtu.be/t0Bt4DEtqa4?t=26s)

How this show never made it to America is just beyond me.